# Interest rate, bond problem

Tags: finance

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Debtor issued a bond on 20 000€ (including interest rate) with
>   maturity rate of 8 months and interest rate of 8% per annum. Month
>   later, the creditor sold the bond to a different person, who discount
>   the bond with 9% interest rate p.a.
>
> How much did the creditor receive for the bond?

My solution is the following:

$FutureValue$ $= P(1+i*t*t/12) = 20000(1+0,08*8*8/12) = 28533$

Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: What does the phrase "including interest rate" mean?  I would assume that a $20000$€ bond at $8\%$ would have a value of $20000(1+0.08\cdot8/12)=21066.67$€ in $8$ months, which is totally out of line with your answer.  Why do you multiply $8/12$ by $8$?

Comment: The creditor must receive less than $20000$ because the higher interest rate will reduce the value.  The future value should not be quadratic in $t$, and you want the present value.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the creditor sold the bond one month after acquiring it, the creditor receives

$$  20000 \times \frac{1+0.08\cdot \frac {8}{12} }{ 1+0.09\cdot \frac {7}{12} } = 20015.8$$

Answer (score 0):

If the bond only pays at maturity, it pays $20000 +\frac 8{12} \cdot 8\% \cdot 20000$ at the end of $7$ months.  You are expected to discount at $9\%$ per year back to present value.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct.  I've never seen a bond that made monthly payments.  In my experience, a bond with a term of less than a year would only pay interest at maturity.  (My experience is old though, so maybe things have changed.)

Comment: @saulspatz:  somehow I read the problem to pay monthly, but I don't see it now.  I have updated